# Android canvas issue

Tags: android

I am new to android. Now I generated two ImageView in my Android XML file. I want to use canvas to draw two circles in each view. But the problem is, how can I deal with the coordinates? How can I know the coordinates? And how can I center them? Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted some code and showed what you have tried to do, we have nothing to go on right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageViews are for displaying image files, normally. If you want to draw your view yourself, you create your own View and override the onDraw method. Here is a class that draws a big red circle inside itself:

```
public class CircleView extends View {

public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint red = new Paint();
    red.setColor(0xffff0000);
    int height = getHeight();
    int width = getWidth();
    int radius = width < height ? width/2 : height/2;
    canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, red);
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot draw cirlces in an ImageView. You can only draw a circle in a bitmap and apply that bitmap to an ImageView.

Or you can create custom views and draw directly on their canvas.

In both cases you need to find the size of these views after they are created. Then you will know the coordinates as the 0,0 starts in the top left corner.